# MySQL Full Text Search in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I am planning to use full text search to search through a potentially large database that is constantly changing. I have read in several sources that full text search is generally not recommended for databases that are constantly changing. I am looking for the best mysql-built-in mehod to search this kind of database. Would fulltext search still be the recommended way of doing searching if I can't implment an outside search engine?

Comment: might help to know what you mean by potentially large. 1 million rows? 100 million rows? etc. Plus, the answer depends heavily on how you intend to handle the search requests. You can easily cache common search terms and rebuild cache via backend scripts.

Comment: It won't be that large. I was thinking about 100,000 rows but these entries would be constantly changing.

Comment: pfft! 100,000 rows is nothing, sir. Unless it happens to store like 10 blob columns all full text then you have no fears with this one. full text away. don't worry about it changing a lot. unless you mean like a chat log with furious users. Even then it might be ok. Servers are pretty tough these days.

Comment: Have you looked at Sphinx? http://sphinxsearch.com/ - this doesn't answer your question, but it may be helpful to look into.

Comment: Thank you very much Kai :)

@juand: Yes, I have looked at Sphinx but as of right now it sadly is not an option for me. :(

Comment: Do go through [MySQL InnoDB full-text-search](http://blogs.innodb.com/wp/2011/07/innodb-fts-performance/) instead of going for a third party search. Although this is still in the labs release. Although for 100,000 entries as @KaiQing says it is nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I used Lucene's port when I had this problem. I don't know whether it is available outside Symfony or Zend but it worked like a charm using the sfLucene plugin. It solved all my text-searching prblems. This site might help you: [lucene tutorial](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/techniques/lucene-php.html)

If you are looking for a MySQL replacement where you can have full text search and relation handling and still be compatible with MySQL go and look around [MariaDB](http://mariadb.org/). It has Shpinx integrated. You can read about the features [here](http://kb.askmonty.org/en/mariadb-versus-mysql-features).

Comment: I think Solr is easier choice

Answer (score 1):

Full text searching is up to the designer. Meaning if you design your DB as a relational DB you lose full text searching in the case of innodb. Myisam allows for full text search but you lose a true relational db. I would suggest moving away from sql db's and use another db if possible. A good suggestion is CouchDB. Obviously, you would have to have a virtual or dedicated server to install CouchDB or any other db for that matter, maybe even asking your host if they can install it for you. In most case the host won't simply install software just for you. There is free hosted CouchDB sites. http://www.iriscouch.com I also understand the work that would be involved in switching everything to use an alternative db. These are the use cases of the developer though.